# Negation of the definition of limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, logic, convergence-divergence, propositional-calculus

A sequence $(x_n) $ of real numbers converges to a real number $ x $ if

For all $\epsilon> 0 $ there exists a natural number $ n_0 $ such that for all $ n \ge n _0 $, $|x_n - x| < \epsilon $.

How to negate this statement? No matter what I try my new statement makes no sense. I am trying to negate it using propositional logic (so the negation of a universal quantifier is an existential quantifier, etc) but I'm getting lost. Please ELI5

Thanks!

Comment: Just a note, propositional logic doesn't involve quantifiers, so "trying to negate it using propositional logic" doesn't make much sense.  You're working in (at least) first order logic if you're using quantifiers.

Answer (score 7):

In ordinary language:

> For *any* real number $x$, there are terms $x_n$ in the sequence with arbitrarily high rank which will remain (at least) at a minimal distance from $x$.

Formally, as there's really an implication in the definition of convergence:
$$\exists x\,\forall\varepsilon\,\exists n_0\,\forall n,\enspace\bigl((n\ge n_0 )\implies(\lvert x_n-x\rvert < \varepsilon)\bigr)$$
we obtain
$$\forall x\,\exists\varepsilon\,\forall n_0\,\exists n,\enspace\bigl((n\ge n_0 )\wedge(\lvert x_n-x\rvert \ge \varepsilon)\bigr)$$

If $x$ is a given number, it becomes somewhat simpler:

> There are terms $x_n$ in the sequence with arbitrarily high rank which will remain at least at a minimal distance from $x$.

Formally:
$$\exists\varepsilon\,\forall n_0\,\exists n,\enspace\bigl((n\ge n_0 )\wedge(\lvert x_n-x\rvert \ge \varepsilon)\bigr)$$

Comment: Shouldn't it read $\forall n_0 \exists n$?

Comment: @cronos2: Oh! yes. Thanks for pointing the typo (so many quantifiers!)

Comment: Your "ordinary language" reading could be confused for "$x$ is a limit point of $x_n$", I think.

Comment: @Ian: I don't think so, sine I begin with ‘For any real $x$’. May be I shoud emphasize ‘any’.

Comment: Never mind, now I see my mistake, your "ordinary language" is for the mathematical statement "$x_n$ does not converge".

Comment: Your formal symbolic version is good, but your “ordinary language” version seems a bit imprecise. Both “…arbitrarily high rank…” and “…a minimal distance…” implicitly introduce a quantifier, and there’s nothing to make clear which of those quantifiers is outermost.  So your “ordinary language” version could be misunderstood as something like $\forall x\, \forall n_0\, \exists n\, \exists \epsilon, ( \ldots )$.  A clearer version might be: “for every $x$, there’s some fixed $\epsilon > 0$ such that there are arbitrarily high terms $x_n$ of the sequence at distance $\geq \epsilon$ from $x$”.

Comment: @Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine: I had to make a compromise between precision and a relative conciseness (I won't dare say elegance…) In my opinion, it is  suppose to be read along the formal version, so they throw light on each other.

Comment: $x$ was a given, it shouldn't be quantified over. The problem is to negate "$x_n$ converges to $x$", not "$x_n$ converges to something".

Comment: This was not clear to me from the context. I'll add  an answer for this case in a moment.

Comment: I see you don't have any quantifier on x_n.  You say there exist terms, which by the plural form you would need some x_m also.  But, doesn't one term suffice?  If one term suffices, where would the existential quantification of x$_n$ go?

Comment: @Doug Spoonwood: The quantifier is  on $n$ in the formal version, and is indicated by ‘there are’ in the ordinary language translation. One term suffices, but as the term has to be of arbitrary high rank, there's by necessity an infinity.

Answer (score 4):

You can write the definition of $(x_n) \to x$ as
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \ \forall n \ge n_0 \ |x_n-x| < \varepsilon$$
When you negate such a statement, the front-loaded quantifiers flip (so the $\forall \exists \forall$ becomes $\exists \forall \exists$, and the quantified proposition is negated (so the $|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$ becomes $|x_n-x| \ge \varepsilon$).

See if you can now negate the statement yourself (and, even better, re-write it in plain English).

Comment: I tried doing this but negating each one alone made a statement of no sense

Comment: If negated correctly (the difficulty is in the implication), it makes sense, at  the cost of some vagueness. Please see my answer.

Comment: @Bernard This answer is fine too. You just have to realize that if a quantifier is quantified over a restricted domain, then in the negation the restriction is preserved.

Comment: @user225430: What do you mean by negating each one alone? If you flip the quantifiers and negate the final proposition, you get
$$\exists \varepsilon > 0 \ \forall n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \ \exists n \ge n_0 \ |x_n - x| \ge \varepsilon$$
What about this doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 2):

$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$  $\forall n$, if $ n \ge n_0$ then $ \ |x_n-x| < \varepsilon$.

Let $p: n\ge n_0$

and $q:\ |x_n-x| < \varepsilon$.

Then, $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} $$\forall n$, $p\implies q$.

Note that $\lnot(p\implies q)=\lnot(\lnot p\lor q)=p\wedge\lnot q$ and $\lnot\varepsilon=\forall$ etc.

**Negation**: $\exists \varepsilon > 0 \ \forall n_0 \in \mathbb{N} $$ \exists n$, $p\wedge\lnot q$ OR $\exists \varepsilon > 0 \ \forall n_0 \in \mathbb{N}  \exists n$, ($n\ge n_0$)$\wedge (|x_n-x|\ge\epsilon$).

Comment: 1. There should be a quantifier over $n$, as it is a quantified variable too. The only constant variables here are $x_n$ (the function, that is) and $x$. 2. You should really write $p$ and $q$ as predicates: $p(n,n_0)=n \geq n_0$, $q(n,\varepsilon)=|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Ian...thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

The completeness of ${\mathbb R}$ allows to formulate this negation in a way that avoids the cumbersome "for all $x$ we don't have convergence to $x\,$". 
It is sufficient to formulate that the sequence in question violates the Cauchy condition, as follows:

There is an $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for any $n_0$ we can find $m$, $n>n_0$ with $|x_m-x_n|\geq\epsilon_0$.

Answer (score 0):

A sequence $(x_n) $ of real numbers does *not* converge to a real number $ x $ iff

$\exists \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}: [\epsilon > 0 \land \forall n_0 \in \mathbb{N}: \exists n\in \mathbb{N}:[n \ge n_0 \land |x_n-x|\ge\epsilon]]$