# A bounded sequence with one accumulation point converges (rigorous proof)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

The proof of my question has been already given verbally [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2078631/608029). I want to show it rigorously as follows.

1- Let $x^*$ be the accumulation point of $(x_k)$.

2- Suppose to the contrary that $(x_k) \not\to x^*$.

3- Then one can write [the negation of the limit definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855740/negation-of-the-definition-of-limit) as follows:
$$
\exists\, \epsilon>0, \, \forall \, k_0 \, \exists \, k\geq k_0 \text{ and } \|x_k-x^*\| \geq \epsilon. \tag{1}
$$
4- $(x_k)$ is a bounded sequence therefore it has a subsequence $(x_{k_j})$ converges to $y^*$.

5- (**Confusion**) using (1) one should be able to write the following:

$$
\|x_{k_j}-x^*\| \geq \epsilon \, \forall \, k_j. \tag{2}
$$

6- Let $k_j \to \infty$ we get the following:

$$
\|y^*-x^*\| \geq \epsilon >0 
$$

which means $y^* \neq x^*$ that contradicts our assumption!

**My question:**

How can I use (1) to get (2) because I have already fixed $\epsilon$ and I do not know how to relate $\forall k_0$ in (1) to have $\forall k_j$. Also, I do not know what is the minimum of $k_j$?

**Note:**

Please address my question and do not use other arguments for proving the statement.

Comment: If you know anything about limit superiors/inferiors and sub-sequential limits, this question becomes trivial. If you're interested, you should try to provide a proof along those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Let $x^*$ be the accumulation point of $(x_k)_{k \geq 1}$.

2- Suppose to the contrary that $(x_k) \not\to x^*$.

3- Then one can write the negation of the limit definition as follows:
$$
\exists\, \epsilon>0, \, \forall \, k^* \, \exists \, k\geq k^* \text{ s.t. } \|x_k-x^*\| \geq \epsilon. \tag{1}
$$

4- Generate a subsequence whose elements all satisfy (1) following below procedure:

4-1- Let $k^*$ be an arbitrary index. Then,

$$
\exists\ k_1\geq k^* \text{ s.t. } \|x_{k_1}-x^*\| \geq \epsilon.
$$

4-2- Let $k^*=k_1+1$. Therefore,
$$
\exists\ k_2\geq k^* \text{ s.t. } \|x_{k_2}-x^*\| \geq \epsilon.
$$

4-3- Let $k^*=k_2+1$ and so on.

4-4- Then, one gets $(x_{k_1}, x_{k_2}, \dots)=(x_{k_j})$ as a subsequence of $(x_k)$ whose elements satisfy $\|x_{k_j}-x^*\| \geq \epsilon$ for all $k_j$.

5- $(x_k)$ is a bounded sequence so is its subsequence, i.e., $(x_{k_j})$.

6- Since $(x_{k_j})$ is a bounded subsequence it has a convergent subsequence $(x_{k_{j_i}})$ converging to $y^*$.

8- Let $k_{j_i} $ go to infinity to get the following:

$$
\|y^*-x^*\| \geq \epsilon >0
$$

8- The above implies $y^* \neq x^*$ which contradicts our assumption!

9- Hence, $(x_k) \to x^*$.

Answer (score 0):

It follows from $(1)$ that the set $\{k\in\Bbb N\mid|x_k-x^*|\geqslant\varepsilon\}$ is an infinite set of natural numbers. Let $m_k$ be its $k$<sup>th</sup> element. Then $(x_{m_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that$$(\forall k\in\Bbb N):|x_{m_k}-x^*|\geqslant\varepsilon.$$But each bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence. Let $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ be such a sequence and let $y^*$ be its limit. Since $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{n_k}=y^*$ and since$$(\forall k\in\Bbb N):|x_{n_k}-x^*|\geqslant\varepsilon,$$we have\begin{align}|y^*-x^*|&=\left|\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{n_k}-x^*\right|\\&=\lim_{k\to\infty}|x_{n_k}-x^*|\\&\geqslant\varepsilon.\end{align}

Comment: I am sorry but you are not answering my question. I still cannot see how from (1) we can get (2). After your third line is clear to me, it is rephrasing my given proof

Comment: I just used the fact that, if you have a convergent sequence $(a_k)_{k\in\Bbb N}$ and a number $a$ such that$$(\forall k\in\Bbb N):a_k\geqslant a,$$then $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k\geqslant a$. I used it with $a_k=|x_{n_k}-x^*|$ and $a=\varepsilon$. Is this what you are missing?

Comment: What I am asking is the relationship between $k_0$, $k$ and $k_j$, how one can get (2) from (1) rigorously?

Comment: What's *not* rigorous in my answer?

Comment: How would you characterize the relationship between $k$'s and $k_j$'s?

Comment: There is no $k_j$ in my answer. The set $\{m_1,m_2,m_3,\ldots\}$ is the set of those natural numbers $m$ such that $|x_m-x^*|\geqslant\varepsilon$, with $m_1<m_2<m_3<\cdots$, and $\{n_1,n_2,n_3,\ldots\}$ is a strictly increasing sequence of elements of $\{m_1,m_2,m_3,\ldots\}$ such that, for some number $y^*$, $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{n_k}=y^*$. Again, what's *not* rigorous in my answer?

Comment: Please read the question. I emphasized that I do not need any other arguments. I want my argument to be filled. You are just throwing your own thoughts without looking what is asked. I do not your proof, I want my proof be completed

Comment: But what is missing? I explained that each $n_k$ is a $m_k$ and that therefore, since you always have $|x_{m_k}-x^*|\geqslant\varepsilon$, you have$$(\forall k\in\Bbb N):|x_{n_k}-x^*|\geqslant\varepsilon,$$which is $(2)$.

Comment: Use my arguments, fill the gaps of my thought. Do not provide me with your thoughts. I do not your indices because I have other way of indexing. Why do not noticing what I am asking and just repeat your first thought?

Comment: Since each $x_{k_j}$ is a $x_k$ and since you always have $\|x_k-x^*\|\geqslant\varepsilon$, you have$$\left\|x_{k_j}-x^*\right\|\geqslant\varepsilon(\forall k_j).$$